# What considerations should be made when designing an SOS feature for a smartwatch

Tags: wearables

I'm designing a contextual SOS for our smartwatch, similar to what apple Watch.

Currently, we have a generic SOS feature. with contextual SOS, the user can also send out additional info to the rescuer.

1. Generic assistant needed
2. Medical assistant needed
3. Security assistant needed

Below is the apple watches intermediate screen that lets the user pick emergency features. It's trigged if you press and hold the watch button.

[image]

in terms of the flow of interaction its

**press+hold** >> **swipe 1 of the options** >> **feature activated**

This seems like quite a bit of effort to be made in an emergency situation.

The solution we're designing may have a similar flow, but we will rethink certain aspects like if it's a swipe or a press. What considerations should be made? With the additional context, more than 1 gesture and additional effort will be needed.

*In situations where maybe the user is injured or in a state of panic, needing to press and hold and then swipe would be physically too demanding.*

Comment: What is a "compass backtrack"?

Answer (score 26):

One important thing to consider, and most probably the reason for the swipe, is to avoid unintentional activation.

You don't want the watch to start calling 911 just because you mistakenly pressed on a button (and didn't even realise it).

On many phones, it's a common issue that you will find the phone with the flashlight or camera on even when you didn't want it, like with the phone in your pocket. That's because there are shortcuts to those, and they are sometimes too sensitive.

Apple are currently having the issue with fully automated alerts on iPhone 14 (Car Crash Detection) which get triggered automatically when the phone detects violent movements/impacts. Apparently [skiers trigger the alert unintentionally very often](https://www.macrumors.com/2022/12/26/iphone-14-car-crash-detection/), and with the phone somewhere in their pocket, they don't even realise it happens (and they don't see the warning screen that allows them to cancel the emergency call).

Even without the "automatic" feature, you want to make sure people are very unlikely to trigger your feature inadvertently. That's the whole reason most actions from a locked phone require a swipe: those are less likely to happen without being explicitly wanted.

Alternatives include multiple presses in a short time (like the 5 presses on the side button of an iPhone which can also trigger emergency calls).

Something that requires just two presses is IMHO way too likely to trigger unwanted calls.

Even back in the days of actual physical buttons (on portable CD players and the like), devices were commonly equipped with a "hold" button which you could slide to make the buttons active or not.

Now, everything depends on the context. If your target are seniors with limited mobility, staying at home, which may fall over and need a button to get help, the simplest the better (single large button). If you target are active people doing all sorts of sports and activities, unintentional presses are a real possibility.

Comment: Exactly this. False positive call outs to emergency services are a serious issue (they waste time that could be spent helping people who legitimately need it), and in some places can even result in legal action for repeat offenders.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Note that the *occasional* false positive is greatly preferable to a false negative. I myself have called emergency services to report a fire I could see that it turned out they were already aware of. You should too, if you see one. I read somewhere that about half of calls are false positives and that seems okay. As long as someone didn't invent a smartwatch that consistently makes accidental emergency calls....

Comment: @user253751 That's not true. An automated system on a generic device is not designed to need that level of reliability to even worry about false negatives. It isn't a life support system. I have no problems with phones not auto-dialing 911 in a car crash because I don't expect it to. I do have problems with phones wasting resources on false positives. With something that has such a large market share, the tiniest rate of false positives will translate to massive amounts of wasted resources, and 911 operators can't ignore calls.

Comment: @user253751 That's not a false positive though - there genuinely was a fire. Prank/hoax calls to the emergency services are a big enough problem that in some countries they are illegal and you can actually serve jail time. They can delay response to a genuine emergency with potentially-fatal results. In practice people are rarely tried for it, but the law is there, and it would equally well cover a company which automates these false-positive calls. So if your smart watch company screws up like that, expect a visit from the police to shut down those features "or else".

Comment: @Graham sure, but at the same time, if your detection is usually detecting true positives but occasionally detects false positives, it can be a good thing overall.

Comment: @user253751 That's the thing though - define "occasionally".  If you're selling consumer-level quantities of these (like 100,000 or so) then your false positive rate had better be *very* low. Even 0.01% per day probably isn't going to be acceptable for the emergency services.

Comment: @Graham "usually detecting true positives" implies maybe a 2:1 ratio of true positives to false positives.

Comment: @Graham that's what's most impressive with the issue raised by the iPhone 14 Crash Detection feature: it's already happened dozens of times (71 times over a single week-end for a single county!) for a phone that was only released 3 months ago, with an issue which seems to be specific to skiers. Hopefully they fix that soon.

Comment: @user253751 On those odds, expect a visit from the police if you're in the UK.

Comment: @jcaron Thanks for your answer. I missed mentioning that our product is an industrial smartwatch, and our current generic SOS feature on the watch hasn't had any false positives so far other than a few outliers.

Comment: @BlueOcean You probably need to tell us a bit more about what "industrial smartwatch" entails, in terms of who uses it, when/where (i.e. do they only wear it at work?), what are the situations that are thought to need that SOS feature, whether that goes directly to 911 or equivalent or to some internal service, what are other features of the watch, what are the possible inputs (touch screen, buttons, etc.), whether you are designing for an existing model or thinking about new hardware. Not sure if it would be more appropriate to edit your question or ask a new one with that additional context.

Comment: If you to reduce interaction to the minimum in the most extreme cases, then you probably want to think about automatic detection like the aforementioned crash detection or the Apple Watch [Fall Detection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208944) feature, which will trigger generic emergency response by default, while you may provide more options if the SOS is triggered manually. In any automatic case, you muse have the watch notify quite obviously the user (taps, rings...) to give them the option to cancel the automated call.

Comment: With false positives there are two paths to go: Either make the device more clever so that it can better distinguish between say a car crash and a skier falling flat on their face. The skier would likely get up and continue skiing - and if they don't then it's not a false positive! The other way is to change the sensitivity. You can choose whether to have more or fewer positives. Accepting fewer alarms means fewer false positives, but some people will be left without needed help.

Answer (score 6):

I, frankly, don't like the presence of equally weighted choices.

Consider this: the user is in need of assistance, panicking, and only has the faintest idea how to use the feature. They don't know what's going, most likely won't stop and think to read what's on the sliders.

Try this: borrow someone's glasses (or take of your own), start the most obnoxious audio recording you can find on full volume and try to use the emergency call feature as fast as you can. Maybe add a drill sergeant shouting at you.

My point is, that someone actually *using* this feature has an entirely different mindset than we have right one. We're looking at it calmly, considering, they'll just be wanting to get help.

Sure, allow an option to add extra details, but make it *very* unobtrusive.

Come to think of it, adding a practice option (a hard to enable toggle which disables the feature for a limited time) is a nice idea.

Comment: +1 for practice option.

Answer (score 5):

General and Security assistance are not as demanding as Medical, and therefore may have a different method of activation. These may include additional inputs to inform responders of the nature and priority of requested assistance. Having to interact multiple times with the interface before the request is sent ought to greatly reduce unintentional requests.

A big challenge with Medical is weighing the cost of false alarms against someone in need not being able to send an alarm, and finding a balance that works for every group using the system.

Some considerations to determine the balance...

Are there multiple methods calling for help? Are there better technologies than a watch? Do people typically work in groups and likely have someone nearby who can help send an alarm?

Is there a quick and simple way to verify the alarm? ...to cancel a false alarm? Can a few seconds delay be added after iniating the alarm, to allow room for cancellation?

What exactly is the cost, in time and resources, for a team to respond to an alarm? What is the range of severity of potential harm and damage from accidents in the environments the watch is used? What is the rate and overall impact of accidents at each location?

A loose interpretation of the [80/20 rule](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-the-pareto-principle-the-8020-rule/) says it will cost 80% of the resources to achieve the final 20% of the goals. Hard to face when thinking about people in need of medical help, but the more resources expended on false alarms mean fewer resources available to help people in need.

Answer (score 2):

You might look to handheld marine DSC sets for inspiration.

The one I have sends a generic ("undesignated") distress indication if the button is held for 3 seconds (to prevent accidental activation, the distress button has a spring-loaded cover, and the unit flashes its display backlight  and makes a noise during the long-press).

When the user is able, specific kinds of distress call can be pre-selected using the unit's usual menu system, in the "calls" sub-menu, before the long press of the distress button.  (The selection reverts back to "undesignated" after ten minutes).

Don't forget to implement a "cancel distress call" for accidental activation (e.g. due to inquisitive children or a situation later resolved).